# In jupyter notebook, pressing tab print "ipynb_checkpoints/" instead of auto-completion

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipython, series

Let say I have a pandas DataFrame called "missing_data" ,  one of the columns is called "normalized-losses".

When I wrote

```
missing_data["normalized-losses"].
```

And then press tab
I expected to see a lot of methods for pandas Series, HOWEVER, this is what I saw

```
missing_data["normalized-losses"].ipynb_checkpoints/
```

What is this, and how could I change it to auto-completion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had same issue recently. It started happening all sudden w/o any particular changes in Jupyter or Python. 
I found this solution that worked for me. 
In Jupyter Notebook run:

```
%config IPCompleter.greedy=True
```